# How to publish 2nd project through Github

Tags: github, github-pages

I have my existing project at the directory:guntukuchaitanya.github.io and thus published by the same name.
Now I have created another project and want to publish it. It is on the internet that, if we want to publish through GitHub, the directory should be named guntukuchaitanya.github.io. On which directory should I upload the new project and how should I publish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your GitHub repository is named **`guntukuchaitanya.github.io`**, then it will be published at **[`guntukuchaitanya.github.io`](https://guntukuchaitanya.github.io/)** and 
**[`guntukuchaitanya.github.io/guntukuchaitanya.github.io`](https://guntukuchaitanya.github.io/guntukuchaitanya.github.io)**.
And if your repository is named only **`guntukuchaitanya`** (i.e., without `.github.io`), then it will be published at [**`guntukuchaitanya.github.io/guntukuchaitanya`**](https://guntukuchaitanya.github.io/guntukuchaitanya)(i.e., username.github.io/repository-name).

Answer (score 0):

While creating new repo you don't need to add .gitHub.io , when you add pages and publish your website then it will add automatically like your repo name .github.io